# Regex to match everything but a single digit

Tags: php, regex, pcre

What would be the regex to match — or not match — everything but a single digit?

For example,

- `stack` should match
- `stack overflow` should match
- `12389237` should match *but*
- `2` should *not* match

I’m on `^[^\d]+$`, but apparently it doesn't match my third condition.

**EDIT:**

This is for PHP by the way.

Comment: Should it also match an empty string because that's not a single digit either?

Comment: If this is for PHP, why do you have a perl tag?

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja Yeah, Anything but the single digit. Cheers.

Comment: @TLP PHP uses PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions) does it not?!

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh Adding the perl tag was confusing a lot of people here, especially since your question in no way made it clear that you were looking for a PHP solution.

Comment: @Chuck: there is a separate SO tag for `PCRE` that is more appropriate than the `Perl` tag.

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for that. The perl tag was actually for command-line perl, but I see your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break it down into two cases. Either match a single character that isn't a digit, or match any string of length 2 or greater:

```
^(\D|.{2,})$
```

Comment: I’m afraid you’ve misunderstood the question.

Comment: @tchrist: Why? It seems to match the criteria asked for.

Comment: Your pattern matches his fourth line, and it is not supposed to.

Comment: No it doesn't. I suggest you try it.

Comment: Also, to take the comment by @Kaivosukeltaja into consideration, if you want it to match the empty string too, just add a `?` before the `$`.

Comment: To the contrary: it absolutely does; witness `perl -le 'for (@ARGV) { print /^(\D|.{2,})$/ ? "PASS" : "FAIL", ": ", $_ }' '"stack" should match' '"stack overflow" should match' '"12389237" should match but' '"2" should not match'` produces PASS on all four. It is not supposed to match the last one. What are you thinking?

Comment: @tchrist I don't think the OP intended for the comments to be part of the matching process.

Comment: I don't think he intends for the "...should match" to be part of the text matched against.

Comment: @VeeArr Why try to match the "everything else" part of the requirement when it is much easier to just say what it should *not* match? `!/^\d$/`.

Comment: Sigh.  Perhaps not. He shouldn’t have formatted it that way then. I stil think `! /^\d$/` is the easiest — and fastest — way to do this.

Comment: @tchrist I just edited my question to indicate that I'm working on PHP. I tested the regex there and it works as intended. Not sure what platform you tested it on?!

Comment: @ChuckUgwuh I misread your question because of how you originally formatted the data.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest is simply to negate a match for a lone digit using normal program logic:

```
 ! /(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)/
```

Encoding that in a single pattern in possible, but annoying:

```
/^(?!.*(?<!\d)\d(?!\d))/
```

or spread out via `/x`:

```
/ ^ (?! .* (?<! \d) \d (?! \d) )/x
```

Or insulated against various multiline circumstances:

```
 / \A (?! .* (?<! \d) \d (?! \d) )/sx
```

See why I said negating a regular positive match is easier?

Here’s the test program:

```
use v5.12;
while (<DATA>) {
    my $got =  / ^ (?! .* (?<! \d) \d (?! \d) )/x;
    print $got ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
    print ": ", $_;

}
__END__
"stack" should match
"stack overflow" should match
"12389237" should match but
"2" should not match
```

Which produces:

```
PASS: "stack" should match
PASS: "stack overflow" should match
PASS: "12389237" should match but
FAIL: "2" should not match
```

---

## EDIT

If you misformatted your question, and if you simply meant that the the strings are actually

```
stack
stack overflow
12389237
2
```

instead, then the simple thing to do is still to negate the match against a single digit:

```
! /^\d$/
```

or more carefully,

```
! /\A\d\z/
```

Building the ɴᴏᴛ operation into the pattern is never pretty.

```
/^ (?! \d $ )/x
```

Here’s another test program:

```
use v5.12;
while (<DATA>) {
    my $got =  /^ (?! \d $ )/x;
    print $got ? "PASS" : "FAIL";
    print ": $_";

}
__END__
stack
stack overflow
12389237
2
```

which reports:

```
PASS: stack
PASS: stack overflow
PASS: 12389237
FAIL: 2
```

Comment: The `\z` vs `$` distinction is more significant than `\A` vs `^`; AFAIK the latter only makes a difference if you interpolate a string regex snippet into a /m context.

Comment: @ysth Alas not anymore.  One must guarantee correct behavior even in the face of an overriding lexically scoped `use re "/msx"` pragma.

Answer (score 2):

Not match a single digit, inverting the match:

```
!/^\d\z/
```

Or just regex with a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!\d\z)/
```

Comment: You might want to use `\Z` or `$` instead. Otherwise, +1 as that is what I was about to post.

Comment: Well if you want to allow a line break before the end of string (i.e `"2\n"`) you can use `$` or `\Z` instead of `\z`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it have to be regex ? For php you do like this

```
is_integer($string) && $string < 10
```

Comment: `Undefined subroutine &main::is_integer called at..`

Comment: Sorry , only for php not perl

Comment: It's not a bad idea, just not a perl solution.

Comment: +1 Looks like your answer is valid now, since the OP said its for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match a string (including the whitespace), and any number that is not a single digit:

```
/^[a-zA-z\s]+|[0-9]{2,}$/gm
```

[RegExr Code](http://regexr.com?30cr3)

Comment: That won’t work on the things that he said it should.  Plus there is no reason ever to enclose a lone `\D` in surrounding square brackets.

Comment: I’m not sure your `/g` or `/m` make sense.  What are you thinking?

Answer (score 0):

```
while(my $line = <DATA>){
    chomp $line;
    if ($line !~ /^\d{1}$/) {
        print "$line    match\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$line    NOT match\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
stack
stack overflow
12389237
2
```

Result:

```
perl regex.pl
stack   match
stack overflow  match
12389237        match
2       NOT match
```

Comment: `{1}` is redundant in all regards except being explicit.